# How to stop the time automatically when all cards are flipped in memory game using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm having trouble here on how to stop the timer in my memory game. I already try the stop function that I found in the tutorial and google but it didn't work out. Here is my code:

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let matchCounter=0;


function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

  if(isMatch){
    matchCounter+=1;
   disableCards();
     if(matchCounter==(cards.length/2)){
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Congratualtions!!!',
        text: 'You finish the game. Thank you for playng.' ,
      })
      }
   }
   else{ unflipCards(); }

  
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  lockBoard = false;
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
 
  
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));

function restartButton(){
  location.reload();
}
var i = 0;
function timer(){
  i++;
  if(i === 1){
    time();
  }
}

var numr = 0;
function countClick(){
  numr ++;
  console.log(numr);
}

/*Timer*/

function time(){
 
  // var target = document.getElementsById("back");
  // target.removeAttribute("onclick");
  var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
  var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
  var totalSeconds = 0;
  setInterval(setTime, 1000);
  
  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  }
  
  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
}

var counterVal = 0;

function incrementClick(){
  updateDisplay(++counterVal);
}
function resetCounter(){
  counterVal = 0;
  updateDisplay(counterVal);
}
function updateDisplay(val){
  document.getElementById("counter-label").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('https://github.com/FoxyStoat/memory-game/blob/master/assets/img/ignasi_pattern_s.png?raw=true');
  ;
}
h1{
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.6);
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 100%;
  margin:5px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin:5px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* transform: scale(1); */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding: 1px; */
  position: absolute;
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  /* background: #1C7CCC; */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.score-panel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 545px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #0d0d0e;
}

.score-panel .stars {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
}

.score-panel .stars li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .timer {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 56%;
}

.score-panel .restart {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}


@media only screen  and (min-device-width: 768px)
  and (max-device-width: 1024px){
     .memory-game{
      width: 860px;
      min-height: 880px;


    }
}
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 812px) {
    .memory-game{
      width: 860px;
      min-height: 880px;


    }
  }

@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 320px)
  and (max-device-width: 568px) {
    .memory-game{
      width: 860px;
      min-height: 880px;


    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Memory Game</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googgameleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Permanent+Marker" > 
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Permanent+Marker" >

<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  
<div class = "container">
  <h1>Memory Game</h1>
  <section class="score-panel">
            <!-- <ul class="stars">
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
            </ul> -->

            <span>Moves <span id = "counter-label">0</span></span>

            <div class="timer">
                <label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
            </div>

            <div class="restart">
                <button onclick="restartButton()" class="fa fa-repeat"></button>
            <!-- <div class="col text-center">
                <button button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
            </div> -->
            </div>
        </section>
  <div class="memory-game ">
            <div class="memory-card" data-framework="aurelia">
              <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/fb.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="fb" />
              <img onclick = "incrementClick();" id="back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
            </div>
            <div class="memory-card" data-framework="aurelia">
              <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/fb.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="fb" />
              <img onclick = "incrementClick(); timer();" id = "back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
            </div>

            
  </div> 

</div>
  

<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src ="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/dist/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Whenever all the cards are flipped the sweet alert will pop up and show the congratulation message but the timer will continue to run despite that the game is finished. I want to stop the timer when all cards are flipped. Thank you in advance for answering. I apologize for my noobness. Kind of new to programming and currently I'm self-thought.

Answer (score 0):

As [the guide for setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval):

`setInterval` returned `intervalID` is a numeric, non-zero value which identifies the timer created by the call to `setInterval()`; this value can be passed to `clearInterval()` to cancel the interval.

So the answer is uses one variable (`timerCtrl` in below demo) to save the return value of `setInterval`, then `clearInterval` when game over.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll('.memory-card');

let hasFlippedCard = false;
let lockBoard = false;
let firstCard, secondCard;
let matchCounter=0;
let timerCtrl = null; // store the return value of setInterval

function flipCard() {
  if (lockBoard) return;
  if (this === firstCard) return;

  this.classList.add('flip');

  if (!hasFlippedCard) {
    hasFlippedCard = true;
    firstCard = this;

    return;
  }

  secondCard = this;
  checkForMatch();
}

function checkForMatch() {
  let isMatch = firstCard.dataset.framework === secondCard.dataset.framework;

  if(isMatch){
    matchCounter+=1;
   disableCards();
     if(matchCounter==(cards.length/2)){
      Swal.fire({
        title: 'Congratualtions!!!',
        text: 'You finish the game. Thank you for playng.' ,
      })
      clearInterval(timerCtrl); // it will stop the timer
      }
   }
   else{ unflipCards(); }

  
}

function disableCards() {
  firstCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);
  secondCard.removeEventListener('click', flipCard);

  resetBoard();
}

function unflipCards() {
  lockBoard = true;

  setTimeout(() => {
    firstCard.classList.remove('flip');
    secondCard.classList.remove('flip');

    resetBoard();
  }, 500);
}

function resetBoard() {
  hasFlippedCard = false;
  lockBoard = false;
  firstCard = null;
  secondCard = null;
 
  
}

(function shuffle() {
  cards.forEach(card => {
    let randomPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * 12);
    card.style.order = randomPos;
  });
})();

cards.forEach(card => card.addEventListener('click', flipCard));

function restartButton(){
  location.reload();
}
var i = 0;
function timer(){
  i++;
  if(i === 1){
    time();
  }
}

var numr = 0;
function countClick(){
  numr ++;
  console.log(numr);
}

/*Timer*/

function time(){
 
  // var target = document.getElementsById("back");
  // target.removeAttribute("onclick");
  var minutesLabel = document.getElementById("minutes");
  var secondsLabel = document.getElementById("seconds");
  var totalSeconds = 0;
  timerCtrl = setInterval(setTime, 1000);
  
  function setTime() {
    ++totalSeconds;
    secondsLabel.innerHTML = pad(totalSeconds % 60);
    minutesLabel.innerHTML = pad(parseInt(totalSeconds / 60));
  }
  
  function pad(val) {
    var valString = val + "";
    if (valString.length < 2) {
      return "0" + valString;
    } else {
      return valString;
    }
  }
}

var counterVal = 0;

function incrementClick(){
  updateDisplay(++counterVal);
}
function resetCounter(){
  counterVal = 0;
  updateDisplay(counterVal);
}
function updateDisplay(val){
  document.getElementById("counter-label").innerHTML = val;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: url('https://github.com/FoxyStoat/memory-game/blob/master/assets/img/ignasi_pattern_s.png?raw=true');
  ;
}
h1{
  font-weight: 400;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 2px rgba(80, 80, 80, 0.6);
}

.container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.memory-game {
  width: 640px;
  height: 640px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  perspective: 100%;
  margin:5px;
}

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25% - 10px);
  height: calc(33.333% - 10px);
  margin:5px;
  /* position: relative; */
  /* transform: scale(1); */
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: transform .5s;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.97);
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.front-face,
.back-face {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /* padding: 1px; */
  position: absolute;
  /* border-radius: 5px; */
  /* background: #1C7CCC; */
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.front-face {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.score-panel {
  text-align: left;
  width: 545px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  color: #0d0d0e;
}

.score-panel .stars {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  color: rgb(24, 23, 23);
}

.score-panel .stars li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.score-panel .timer {
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  left: 56%;
}

.score-panel .restart {
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}


@media only screen  and (min-device-width: 768px)
  and (max-device-width: 1024px){
     .memory-game{
      width: 860px;
      min-height: 880px;


    }
}
@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 375px)
  and (max-device-width: 812px) {
    .memory-game{
      width: 860px;
      min-height: 880px;


    }
  }

@media only screen
  and (min-device-width: 320px)
  and (max-device-width: 568px) {
    .memory-game{
      width: 860px;
      min-height: 880px;


    }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">

<title>Memory Game</title>
<link rel = "stylesheet" href ="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
<!-- <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googgameleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Permanent+Marker" > 
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">-->

    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Coda">
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Permanent+Marker" >

<link href="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/dist/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  
<div class = "container">
  <h1>Memory Game</h1>
  <section class="score-panel">
            <!-- <ul class="stars">
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
                <li><i class="fa fa-star"></i></li>
            </ul> -->

            <span>Moves <span id = "counter-label">0</span></span>

            <div class="timer">
                <label id="minutes">00</label>:<label id="seconds">00</label>
            </div>

            <div class="restart">
                <button onclick="restartButton()" class="fa fa-repeat"></button>
            <!-- <div class="col text-center">
                <button button type = "button" class = "btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
            </div> -->
            </div>
        </section>
  <div class="memory-game ">
            <div class="memory-card" data-framework="aurelia">
              <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/fb.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="fb" />
              <img onclick = "incrementClick();" id="back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
            </div>
            <div class="memory-card" data-framework="aurelia">
              <img class="front-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/fb.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="fb" />
              <img onclick = "incrementClick(); timer();" id = "back" class="back-face" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/resources/dist/img/card.png" class = "img-fluid"alt="yugioh" />
            </div>

            
  </div> 

</div>
  

<script src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src ="<?php echo base_url();?>resources/dist/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: the timer stopped. thank you for your help Sphinx. I really appreciated it. X)